# Is Janeway fated to die?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

At the end of the Voyager series, Admiral Janeway travels 26 years into the past to quicken Voyager's travel home.  She sacrifices herself in the process.  Does this mean that this timeline's Janeway is fated to do the same or can she alter the timeline even more by improving on the previous attempt and possibly making it back alive?

Comment: “Does this mean that this timeline's Janeway is fated to do the same” — well, probably not. She changed the past, and got pretty much everyone on the ship home alive, so *this* Janeway doesn’t need to go back in time to fix anything. And I think it’s fair to say [she’s already sacrificed herself enough times already](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Kathryn_Janeway#Alternate_realities_and_timelines).

Comment: Star Trek is notoriously inconsistent about time travel but I can't think of a single story where fate reigns. If they are consistent about anything, it's probably that the future is always an alternate timeline and free will reigns.

Comment: Janeway is a human, so yes, she is fated to die.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite but if she doesn't go back then wouldn't time revert causing a paradox? I don't think the time ships from the future need yet another incident on their hands.

Comment: Didn’t the Abramsverse discard everything that would lead to Voyager at all?  Maybe she will never be born.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: “if she doesn't go back then wouldn't time revert causing a paradox?” Well, *obviously* in real life it would, but this is fiction!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite _in real life_ ? ;)

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen "Obviously in real[istic] life it would"

Comment: The timelines in which Janeway dies are the only timelines worth living in.

Comment: I thought my answer to this was pretty solid. Also, I managed to use the word *obviate*. If that's not worthy of an acceptance, I don't know what is... :-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**No.** The future Janeway altered the past, obviating the need for present Janeway to travel [back in time in the future](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8w95xIdH4o&feature=youtu.be&t=24s). This evidently resulted in the destruction of the previous timeline (the one that Future Janeway came from) and the creation of a brand new timeline in which the Voyager returns to Earth substantially sooner.

[image]

You may wish to note that this is precisely the same plotline as [Voy: Timeless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeless_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)), where Harry and Chakotay pinch a Borg time travel device (possibly even the same one used by Janeway in the parallel timeline) and use it to alter the past.

> **KIM:** *Wait a second. If I sent a message from the future and changed the past, then that future would no longer exist, right? So,
>   how could I have sent the message in the first place? Am I making any
>   sense?*
>
> **JANEWAY:** *My advice in making sense of temporal paradoxes is simple. **Don't even try.***

Comment: Well, she's most likely still fated to die, just not at any particular point.  Though I suppose it's possible Q will renew his old crush on her and give her immortality.

Comment: Star trek fonts exist? My question is, wouldn't time revert the instant captain janeway makes the choice to not go back? After all, matter and energy can be neither created nor destroyed. Therefore, for her to not go back would mean that past-future janeway ceases to exist and everything reverts. I guess Star Trek uses an unrealistic time travel model.

Comment: So does that render the years of _Voyager_ episodes all things that never happened?

Comment: @Thegreatduck - That's not how time travel works in Star Trek.

Comment: @Dronz - No. The timeline only diverged *after* Admiral Janeway's arrival.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49012/discussion-between-williham-totland-and-thegreatduck).